# Reverse Geocoding - Google Maps v3

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

To start, I'm not very good at programming and am just a beginner so please keep that in mind with any responses.
   My problem is with reverse geocoding using Google Maps v3. I have found plenty of examples on the internet and have gotten the basics of my map working, however the reverse geocoding part is frustrating me in that I simply cannot get it to work. I keep on getting an error of "object HTMLDivElement". The part of the code that I am having trouble with is:

```
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();  

  var point = new google.maps.LatLng(38.41054600530499, -112.85153749999995);
    geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': point }, function (results, status) {
    if (status !== google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        alert(status);
    }
    // This is checking to see if the Geoeode Status is OK before proceeding
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        console.log(results);
        var address = (results[0].formatted_address);
    }}
    )
  var marker = createMarker(point,"Marker 1", point + "<br> Closest Matching Address:" + address)
```

The map still loads, yet the infobox reads "38.41065600530499, -112.8515374999995; Closest Matching Address:["object HTMLDivElement"]

So what is it that I need to change? I'm certain that the code listed above has something wrong with it, but what exactly?

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: Try console.log(ing) the address object and see what it contains ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The geocoder is asynchronous.  You must be testing in IE and have a div with id="address".

```
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();  

  var point = new google.maps.LatLng(38.41054600530499, -112.85153749999995);
  geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': point }, function (results, status) {
    if (status !== google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      alert(status);
    }
    // This is checking to see if the Geoeode Status is OK before proceeding
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      console.log(results);
      var address = (results[0].formatted_address);
      // create the Marker where the address variable is valid
      var marker = createMarker(point,"Marker 1", point + "<br> Closest Matching Address:" + address)
    }
  });
```

Comment: Worked, however messes with the rest of code (posted rest of code for reference).

Comment: Could you be a little more specific?  What does "messes with the rest of the code" mean?  What problem does it cause?  Perhaps a fiddle that replicates the issue might be helpful as well.

Comment: Sorry for not being specific enough. What I meant was that the second point I had on my map wasn't showing up. I was able to fix the code thanks to your example and placing all the markers in the correct areas. So now my map is working perfectly. Thanks a lot of your help :)